# jQuery call to functions

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var x;
x=$(document);
x.ready(initEvents);

function initEvents()
{
    var x;
    x = $("#send");
    x.click(pressButton);
    x = $("#clean");
    x.click(cleanForm);
}

/*this method  validates the form*/
function pressButton()
{   
    $("#form1 :input").attr("disabled", true);

    $("#form1").validate(
    {   rules:
        {
            //sets the rules for validate
        },
        messages:
        {
            //sets the message for validates
        },
        submitHandler: function (form)
        {
            //send the form
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that if a put this line `$("#form1 :input").attr("disabled", true);` the validates don't executes but if I commented the validate function works great. The question is why can't I execute the two lines? What am I doing wrong in the code?

Comment: it may be that your Validation plugin doesn't process form elements that are `disabled`.

Comment: What do you mean with *validates don't executes*? My guess is that disabled elements are not checked as they are not sent to the server anyway.

Comment: @Felix Kling thanks for asking, when i talk about the validates don't execusctes it's that don't use the validation

Comment: Why are you disabling the fields at all? (I should have asked that first).

Comment: according to to the jquery validation options disabled elements are ignored.  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions look at the ignore option it clearly states.

Comment: @Felix Kling  you're right doesn't have any sense to disabled the form and then send it, so i change the called and it work thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this, disabled the form after the validation putting the line in the submithanlder of the validation

```
/*this method  validates the form*/
function pressButton()
{   


$("#form1").validate(
{   rules:
    {
        //sets the rules for validate
    },
    messages:
    {
        //sets the message for validates
    },
    submitHandler: function (form)
    {
        //disable the form
        $("#form1 :input").attr("disabled", true);
        //send the form
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is your actual problem here, but it's worth noting that you should pay attention to [getting your curly braces right when you're working with JavaScript](http://encosia.com/2011/03/21/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/). Adding the line break between the key name and the opening brace of the value may cause the key name to be interpreted as [a JavaScript label](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Labels) in some cases.

It would be better to generally use this style, to avoid running into strange errors later on:

```
// Why complicate this?
$(document).ready(initEvents);    

function initEvents() {
  $("#send").click(pressButton);
  $("#clean").click(cleanForm);
}

/*this method  validates the form*/
function pressButton() {   
  $("#form1 :input").attr("disabled", true);

  $("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
      // the rules for validate
    },
    messages: {
      //sets the message for validates
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      //send the form
    }
  });
}
```